# Assign quantitative variables to data points in the data frames in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment, assign

I am trying to assign numbers 1, 2, and 3 to a data frame with 80 variables and 250 observations (financial time series). In other words, I want to group each data point into 1, 2, and 3 based on criteria:

I am thinking there is some `if`functions that may do this. I have tried to search around for this method, but I am not sure how to word the problem properly to give good results.

For example, using this data frame which is constructed similar to mine. Notice that the values in the vectors can change. Think of the values in `dat1` as scores between 1 and 5.

```
dat1 = data.frame(
  a = c(2.1,2.3,2.3), 
  b = c(3.6,3.7,3.8), 
  c = c(1.2,1.3,1.4),
  d = c(2.4, 2.3, 3.2), 
  e = c(3.9, 1.2, 3.1))

    a   b   c   d   e
1 2.1 3.6 1.2 2.4 3.9
2 2.3 3.7 1.3 2.3 1.2
3 2.3 3.8 1.4 3.2 3.1
```

- If the value is between 1 and 2 in `dat1`, assign value 1.
- If the value is between 2 and 3 in `dat1`, assign value 2.
- If the value is greater than 3 in `dat1`, assign value 3.

Which I want the end result to become:

```
dat2=
  a b c d e
1 2 3 1 2 3
2 2 3 1 2 1
3 3 3 1 3 3
```

and then sum the rows from `dat1` if the data points from `dat2` have the same values to create:

```
dat3=
   X1  X2  X3
1 1.2 4.5 7.5
2 2.5 4.6 3.7
3 1.4 0.0 13.4
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I hope this was understandable.

Comment: Look at `ifelse`, as in `dat1[] <- lapply(dat1, function(x) ifelse(x<2, 1, ifelse(x>3, 3, 2)))
`

Comment: It sounds like something like `sapply(c(1,2,3), function(x) sum(dat1*(dat2 == x)))`, but this does not match the example output.

Comment: @coffeinjunky my output was wrong, but it is edited now. your first suggestion worked, but it seems like your second suggestion doesn't match `dat3`.

Comment: Can you explain how 1.2 and 4.5 in the first row are calculated?

Comment: In `dat2` we see that only `c1` has the value `1` in row 1. So `sum` of row 1 of `dat1` will become 1.2. In `dat2`again, we see that there are 2 values with categorical value `2` which is number `2.1` and `2.4` in `dat1`, summing them together will give 4.5

Comment: I assume third row, first column in dat2 should be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `floor` to get the group id , the we using `apply`

```
d1=floor(dat1)
d1[d1>3]=3
d1
  a b c d e
1 2 3 1 2 3
2 2 3 1 2 1
3 3 3 1 3 3

xx=cbind(d1,dat1)

bl <- apply(xx,1, function(x){
    aggregate(x[6:10], by=list(Category=x[1:5]), FUN=sum)
})

df=Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Category",all=T), bl)
df$Category=NULL
 t(df)
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
x.x  1.2  4.5  7.5
x.y  2.5  4.6  3.7
x    1.4   NA 13.4
```

Comment: @coffeinjunky ummm, just adding `d1[d1>3]=3`

Comment: For some reason, I do not get the same `d1`as you. But I really think your suggestion should work!

Comment: How can I do this for multiple columns? I have 80 columns in my real data set.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are basically running `floor` on dat1. If you want to do this rowwise, I would convert to long format first and then back to wide. Here is an example using data.table

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table and save row id
setDT(dat1)[, id := .I]

# convert to long and the back to wide using the row id and `floor` 
dcast(melt(dat1, id = "id"), # convert to long
      id ~ ifelse(value > 3, 3, floor(value)), # convert back to wide while aggregating
      sum) # calculating sum by group
#    id   1   2    3
# 1:  1 1.2 4.5  7.5
# 2:  2 2.5 4.6  3.7
# 3:  3 1.4 0.0 13.4
```

Comment: Or `id ~ cut(value, breaks = c(1:3, Inf))`

Answer (score -1):

Use case_when() from dplyr inside mutate on every column